# How do you exclude .svn directories from search in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

I have to "look in:" a subfolder of the project because the entire project is very large and takes too long to search through.

I also have AnkhSVN installed and wonder if a setting in the plugin could help too.

Answer (score 4):

If you use "Find in files" instead of the standard search, you can search a subfolder for file types you specify.

However, it's a lot easier to perform this kind of task using the Ultrafind add-on (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9fa9fdd7-1c06-45e3-a9f3-0381caab8f94) which you can use to exclude specific file patterns.

Comment: This link says "This item is not yet published." for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, it seems that despite all the wonderful functionality of Visual Studio, the easiest way to omit .svn directories from searches is to use Windows Explorer to navigate to the .svn directory, right click the folder, go to Properties, and click the Hidden checkbox under Properties.

If you then re-open your Visual Studio solution, it should keep those files out of the searches.

Comment: It is hidden here, VS still searches it.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way is to simply include every other file type *except* .svn and .svn-base etc.

Try using this set of wildcards and add any other valid extensions beginning with S that you might need:

```
*.sql;*.svc;*.;*.?;*.??;*.a??;*.a???;*.a????;*.b??;*.b???;*.b????;*.c??;*.c???;*.c????;*.d??;*.d???;*.d????;*.e??;*.e???;*.e????;*.f??;*.f???;*.f????;*.g??;*.g???;*.g????;*.h??;*.h???;*.h????;*.i??;*.i???;*.i????;*.j??;*.j???;*.j????;*.k??;*.k???;*.k????;*.l??;*.l???;*.l????;*.m??;*.m???;*.m????;*.n??;*.n???;*.n????;*.o??;*.o???;*.o????;*.p??;*.p???;*.p????;*.q??;*.q???;*.q????;*.r??;*.r???;*.r????;*.t??;*.t???;*.t????;*.u??;*.u???;*.u????;*.v??;*.v???;*.v????;*.w??;*.w???;*.w????;*.x??;*.x???;*.x????;*.y??;*.y???;*.y????;*.z??;*.z???;*.z????;*.0??;*.0???;*.0????;*.1??;*.1???;*.1????;*.2??;*.2???;*.2????;*.3??;*.3???;*.3????;*.4??;*.4???;*.4????;*.5??;*.5???;*.5????;*.6??;*.6???;*.6????;*.7??;*.7???;*.7????;*.8??;*.8???;*.8????;*.9??;*.9???;*.9????;
```

(I had to use various combinations of ? instead of a single * because the final extension could still be .svn)